# MVC3 code first: migrations and generating the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, code-first, dbmigrator

I'm a bit lost how I should get the entity framework to work with automatic migration. I want:

- The database to be created automatically when it doesnt exist
- The database to be updated automatically when the model changed

For the latter I'm using DbMigrator. It is rather slow so I don't want to run it every request, and also I have multiple databases in the same application so it cant go in Application_Start which is why I put it in Session_Start like this:

```
    if (Session["started"] == null)
    {
        // this takes care of any database updates that might be necessary. 
        MigrationConfiguration configuration = new MigrationConfiguration();
        DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
        List<string> pm = migrator.GetPendingMigrations().ToList();
        if (pm.Count > 0)
        {
            migrator.Update();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Session["started"] = "started";
    }
```

Not sure if this is the right way to do it but it seems to work, however it doesnt actually generate the database when it doesnt exist. It gives me a "Cannot open database "db" requested by the login"

I had this working before with the following:

```
    Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(new InitializerIfModelChange());
```

This drops the database and generates seed data which is fine for when the database doesnt exist but it also is triggers when the database is changed (in which case I would like DbMigrator to handle it) This was in Application_Start before but I'm not sure what to do with it. I'm afraid that it will conflict with the DbMigrator. How would I set this all up in order to achieve the two things described earlier?

Answer (score 1):

I manually run the `Update-Database` in the package manager whenever the database needs to be changed. Initially I used the `Database.SetInitializer` like you did to create the database but have it commented out now.

Checkout [Entity Framework 4.3 Automatic Migrations Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx) for more advanced help.

This should work for what you want, then if you need to create a new database just add `Database.SetInitializer<NewDBContext>(new NewDBInitializer());` like you had, build and run. Then comment it out so it doesn't run in the future on a model change and instead use the `Update-Database` command in the package manager.